# С++ виртуальный базовый класс

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте есть иерархия классов, у каждого класса конструктор имеет входные данные, без входных данных у конструкторов все работает, меня интересует как передавать аргументы от производных классов (если их несколько) одному базовому виртуальному классу.

```
   class E{

    public:
       int i;

          E(int a){

       i=a;
     }
          ~E(){

      }

   };

 class A:virtual public E{

   public:

    A(int a,int b):E(b){

       i=a;
   }
};
  class B:virtual public E{

  int x;
 public:

   B(int a,int b):E(b){

       x=a;
   }
};

  class C :public B,public A{

    int m;
    public:

      C(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e):B(b,e),A(c,d){

         i=a;
       }

          };
```

Помогите исправить.

Comment: Что-то я не понял. В каком производном классе? Вы и так в классах A и В передаете в Е параметры для конструктора.

Comment: А из какого класса будут использоваться параметры A или B? Насколько я понимаю если класс наследуется как виртуальный то копия этого класса не создается.

Comment: У вас какая-то ошибка вылезает при компиляции? Или что?

Comment: Да вылезает ошибка, а без без входных параметров у конструкторов объекты классов создаются без всяких проблем и все отлично компилируется, так что проблема скорее всего в передаче параметров конструкторам.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так это классическая проблема множественного наследования. Реально в классе С появляются 2 переменные i, обе из которых принадлежат пространству имен C, только одна из них в базовом классе класса А, другая - класса В. Компилятор оказывается с состоянии неопределенности: какую использовать?

Надо вручную указать, какую переменную, из какого пространства имен, Вы хотите проинициализировать в теле конструктора

```
 C(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e):B(b,e),A(c,d){
     A::i=a;
   }
```

или

```
 C(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e):B(b,e),A(c,d){
     B::i=a;
   }
```

Вот поэтому я считаю множественное наследование одной из самых опасных частей С++

Comment: Спасибо это именно то что мне было нужно.

Answer (score 0):

У меня ваш код порождает следующую ошибку: "no matching function for call to 'E::E()".
Б. Страуструп пишет: "Язык гарантирует, что конструктор виртуального базового класса вызывается (явно или неявно) ровно один раз - **из конструктора полного объекта (то есть из конструктора наиболее производного класса)**."
Ваш конструктор С(int,int,int,int,int) не вызывает конструктор виртуального базового класса E(int), компилятор пытается неявно вызвать конструктор по умолчанию E(), но не может, поскольку умолчательный конструктор у вас не определен.
Конструктор для класса C может выглядеть так:
    `C(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e): E(a), B(b,e), A(c,d) {}`

Answer (score -1):

Да уж, вопрос не совсем понятен, но, как я ,наверное, правильно понял, вам нужен класс, хранящий какие-либо данные на протяжении работы программы. Советую использовать простейший в реализации паттерн "Одиночка"

[Паттерн "Одиночка"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.BD.D0.B0_C.2B.2B)